# Access php multidimensional array key based on a variable string

Tags: php, arrays

I have stored the XML path to items in a string like this: `response->items->item`.

What I need to do is to access an array called $xml_array like this:

$xml_array['response']['items']['item']

When I write it in the code it works. The thing is that I want it to be done on the fly.

I use this to convert `response->items->item` to `['response']['items']['item']`:

```
$xml_path = 'response->items->item';
$explode_path = explode('->', $xml_path);
$correct_string = false;

foreach($explode_path as $path) {
   $correct_string .= '[\''.$path.'\']';
}
```

the problem is that I can't access `$xml_array` by doing this: `$xml_array[$correct_string]`

So I end up with this:

```
$xml_tag = 'title';
$xml_path = 'response->items->item';

$correct_string = '$items = $xml2array';

$explode_path = explode('->', $xml_path);

foreach($explode_path as $path) {
    $correct_string .= '[\''.$path.'\']';
}
$correct_string .= ';';

eval($correct_string);
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item[$xml_tag].'<br />';
}
```

and access the `$xml_array` array through `$items` array. Is there any way I can do this and avoid using eval()?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$xml_tag = 'title';
$xml_path = 'response->items->item';

$explode_path = explode('->', $xml_path);

$items = $xml2array[$explode_path[0]][$explode_path[1]][$explode_path[2]];

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item[$xml_tag].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this! what if I want to automatically generate the $items variable instead of manually writing $explode_path[0] etc? After all I will retrieve this from MySQL.

Comment: OK got it: `$explode_path = explode('->', $xml_path);

$count_explode = count($explode_path);
$items = $xml2array;
for($i=0; $i<$count_explode; $i++) {
 $items = $items[$explode_path[$i]];
}`

Answer (score 6):

I'm really glad that your goal is to stop using `eval()`.  :-)

If I've understood you correctly, you have an array of `$items` and you're trying to locate things in it based on the contents of `$xml_path`.

I obviously haven't tested this on your data, but what about something like this?

```
<?php

$xml_path = 'response->items->item';

$explode_path = explode('->', $xml_path);

foreach($items as $item) {
  $step = $item;
  foreach($explode_path as $path) {
    $step = $step[$path];
  }
  echo $step . '<br />';
}
```

The idea is that for each of the $items, you step through the exploded path, narrowing your search as you go by refining `$step` perhaps to some unknown depth.

This of course assumes that for any value of $xml_path, there WILL be a corresponding item set in the $items array.  Otherwise, you'll want to add some error handling.  (You probably want error handling anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $array = [];
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $inputs[] = [
            $item->name => $item->value
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.