How to get particular value in multi dimensional array while have exact key string
 $tstr = 'jsonObj["Results"]["Tests"]["child"] ';
 print_r($$tstr);


Warning:  Undefined variable $jsonObj["Results"]["Tests"]["child"]

How to get particular value while have the key string?
Thanks
looking for the value of $jsonObj["Results"]["Tests"]["child"]

Something similar to this would help you

Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264853/how-to-get-value-from-nested-array-using-string

Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883682/access-php-multidimensional-array-key-based-on-a-variable-string . Basically the same concept every time - take the string and split it out, then loop over the resulting list to go down the nested layers of the array. If you can alter the format of that string you've built to be easier to explode on a specific character then you'll have a happier time. e.g. $tstr = 'Results_Tests_child'; or similar. Make sure to remove that stray space at the end
